# "time passed" vs "time passed by"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs, verb-usage

> Time ________ and they still hadn't heard anything from their son.

- A. Passed
- B. Passed by
- C. Went
- D. Went on

I think it can't be C or D. But I also don't know if it's A or B.

Answer (score 3):

Choice A  "passed" is by far the most natural of the given choices. The phrase "time passed" is a very common one.  One could also use "time passed by", but that is less likely in this context. "went by" would be natural, and the meaning would be about the same as "passed".